# How to modify font zoom rate?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know Zoom In/Out command change zoom level  by 20%.

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility

In my display, the font size often too small or big.
I hope to ajust more precisely.

Comment: Why would that be? Do you change displays on a regular basis? Did you try to enable [mouse wheel zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30192884/is-it-possible-to-configure-control-scroll-wheel-to-increase-decrease-zoom-in)? You could also manually change that value to suite your case.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio Code, the zoom level increases or decreases by 20%
each time that Zoom is executed.
I assume that 20% is too much and you would like to use finer
zoom increments.

The setting that contains the increment is called
`customWindowZoom.zoomLevelChangeValue`.

For an easier user-interface for changing this setting, see the extension
[Custom Window Zoom](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=craigb85.custom-window-zoom):

> This Visual Studio Code extension allows you to set the zoom level
>   increment/decrement level. By default VSCode increments/decrements by
>   '1' which equates to ~20%.
>
> With this extension you can set the user settings,
>   "customWindowZoom.zoomLevelChangeValue": (value), to any decimal and
>   the increment/decrement action will increase by whatever you set it
>   to.
>
> For Example, set zoom level to .1, if you zoom in it will be .2 and if
>   you zoom out it would be .1 again.

Comment: Has this been deprecated?

Comment: @skytwosea: Doesn't seem to have changed - [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility).

Comment: No, I think it has. The "customWindowZoom.zoomLevelChangeValue" setting no longer works/exists in my up-to-date install, and that setting is not found on in that link you just posted. You can set the "window.zoomLevel" setting but that doesn't alter the change value.

Comment: "When you adjust the zoom level with the View > Zoom In / Out commands, the zoom level is persisted in the window.zoomLevel setting. The default value is 0 and each increment/decrement changes the zoom level by **20 percent**."

Comment: I know. I have read through the link closely. I want to change the zoom increment from 20% to 5% or 10%, but the setting you suggested in your answer to do this is no longer available: `customWindowZoom.zoomLevelChangeValue` is not accessible in version 1.85.0. Currently, I have `window.zoomLevel` set to -0.5, but using view > zoomIn/zoomOut changes `window.zoomLevel` back to an integer and changes it by 20%. Things have changed, and your answer is no longer accurate.

Comment: @skytwosea: The details change - this answer is from 2019 after all, but the underlying facts have not changed, unfortunately. What you're trying to do was impossible with VScode from 2019 and unfortunately is still the case in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the mentioned extension is no longer functional, which isn't too surprising given that it hasn't been updated in more than 5 years.
However, an alternative extension has been created: [Zoomer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=anthonyattard.zoomer).

To ensure that each increment/decrement changes the zoom level by, for example, 10% instead of the default 20%, install that extension and add `"zoomer.zoomIncrement": 0.1` to `settings.json`.